# Timed out waiting for driver server to stop

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have written a scrapper using selenium which uses chrome driver. It works well but some time it fails to quit chrome driver with following exception

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to stop.
Build info: version: '4.1.3', revision: '7b1ebf28ef'
System info: host: '45-79-216-229.ip.linodeusercontent.com', ip: '45.79.216.229', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.18.0-348.12.2.el8_5.x86_64', java.version: '11.0.14'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [66aa12cc87af0a6cf095436a6bbece90, quit {}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 102.0.5005.61, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 102.0.5005.61 (0e59bcc00cc4..., userDataDir: /tmp/.com.google.Chrome.DhJaWB}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:45009}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:45009/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 102.0.5005.61, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 66aa12cc87af0a6cf095436a6bbece90
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:132)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:567)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:622)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:626)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:463)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.quit(ChromiumDriver.java:293)
```

**Code**
I am adding my code here.

```java
public class SeleniumScraper {

    private WebDriver driver;

    public SeleniumScraper() {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        ChromeOptions options = this.getDefaultChromeOptions();
        this.driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    public WebDriver getPage(String url) {
        this.driver.get(url);
        return driver;
    }

    public boolean quitDriver() {
        this.driver.quit();
        return true;
    }

    protected ChromeOptions getDefaultChromeOptions() {
        HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<>(2);
        chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", false);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
        options.setHeadless(true);
        return options;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried

```java
   driver.close();
   driver.quit();
```

it does not throw any exception now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).